# Dialog modal in Autocad Map (2013)

Tags: dictionary, gis, autocad, cad

I have a plan with a building and I was wondering if there is any way to attach to that entity something like a dialog modal (pop up).

When you click on the centroid (or on the contour of the building) I want to open a pop up asking you to select one of the entrace (I have entrance A, entrance B, entrance C). I want to accomplish this behaviour and when you'll select an entrance 1, a pop up or a document will open showing you all the apartmanets in that entrance of the building.

I'm trying to make a GIS-based cadastral system.

**Is it possible to have something like this in Autocad Map?**

Someone told me about a solution similar with this in ArcGIS but unfortunately I can't use ArcGIS.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a double-click handler that connects to the Application.BeginDoubleClick event, and you can uniquely identify the entity you're clicking on (I'd use an Xrecord on the entity) you can accomplish what you need.

Once you have the entity objectid and you know the user has double-clicked, you can display your form and prompt the user for required information.

Comment: Is there any way you could be more specific. Like try doing the entity block then write this in cmd etc.. It's the first time when I try something like this. Don't forget I asked about 2013. And thank you for your answer. I will try to get more information from the Internet based on your answer but I'm looking forward hearing from you again!

Comment: I'm currently programming on Map 2013 so I know this is possible.  Here's an excellent article on properly implementing a double-click handler: http://drive-cad-with-code.blogspot.ca/2013/03/update-custom-double-click-action-using.html

Comment: Didn't knew I have to enter into programming to make something like this. Thank you a lot James.